# Product of edge lengths of a complete graph

Tags: complex-numbers, products

While trying to come up with an interesting math problem I came up with a solution to the following:

Consider $N$ equally spaced points on a circle of radius $1$.  Line segments connect these points such that each point is connected to every other point by exactly one line segment.  What is the product of the lengths of all of these line segments?

For clarification, the resulting graph (a common doodle) for $N$ = $13$ looks like this:

[image: Example for N Equals Thirteen]

The solution I found is that the product $P$ is given by

$P=N^{N/2}$

I'm sure this same problem has been solved before and with more rigor but I have not been able to find a solution to this problem (or even the problem statement) online.  Does anyone know of a proof for this solution or know where to look to see if someone else has solved this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I don't know if anyone else has solved this problem, but I would advise you to consider symmetries, such as all the edges between two adjacent nodes are the same length. This should allow you to simplify this problem a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use complex numbers.  The points can be regarded as
$$e^{2k\pi i/N}\quad\hbox{for}\quad k=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1\ .$$
The product of all the lengths from $1$ (that is, from the point with $k=0$) is
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1}|1-e^{2k\pi i/N}|
  =\left|\prod_{k=1}^{N-1}(1-e^{2k\pi i/N})\right|\ .$$
Now the product is
$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^N-1}{z-1}=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{Nz^{N-1}}{1}=N\ .$$
The product is the same for all $N$ roots so we get $N^N$; but every length has been included twice ("once from each end"), so the correct answer is
$$\sqrt{N^N}=N^{N/2}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks, this starts out the same as my solution but you finished it much more elegantly.  Instead of realizing that each length would be included twice I had to use the ratio of the number of each size length in the graph to the number of each size length when only considering lengths from 1.